# I can't seem to get my code to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a coffee shop transaction form. I've tried everything i know. but still nothing. [this is a test design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgQuo.jpg) I have here the Item Name and Item Size. Each item will have different prices, example: Item X (size a = 5, size b = 10, size c = 15), Item Y (size a = 6, size b = 11, size c = 12)... then a quantity will be entered, after clicking the "ADD ITEM" button, the sub Total(not sure) should appear on the boxes on the left.

how should i make this work? thanks.

PS: sorry if you find it hard to understand what i say. thanks tho!
just to add, i used the sizes offered by star bucks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sbwadcss.css">


<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var TotalPrice=0;

        function chooseItem()
        {

            var itemPrice = parseInt(0);
            var itemName = document.getElementById('itemName').value;
            var itemSize = document.getElementById('itemSize').value;
            var qty = document.getElementById('QuanVal').value.trim();
            var subTotal = document.getElementById('subTotal').value;



            if (qty!="")
            {
                if (qty.match(/^[0-9]+$/))
                {
                    if(itemName=="Caffe Latte")
                    {
                        if(itemSize=="Tall")
                            itemPrice = (75*qty);
                        else if(itemSize=="Grande")
                            itemPrice = (105*qty);
                        else(itemSize=="Venti")
                            itemPrice = (135*qty);
                    }
                    if(itemName=="Caffe Americano")
                    {
                        if(itemSize=="Tall")
                            itemPrice = (80*qty);
                        else if(itemSize=="Grande")
                            itemPrice = (100*qty);
                        else(itemSize=="Venti")
                            itemPrice = (120*qty);
                    }
                    if(itemName=="Cappuccino")
                    {
                        if(itemSize=="Tall")
                            itemPrice = (70*qty);
                        else if(itemSize=="Grande")
                            itemPrice = (95*qty);
                        else(itemSize=="Venti")
                            itemPrice = (120*qty);
                    }
                    if(itemName=="Espresso")
                    {
                        if(itemSize=="Tall")
                            itemPrice = (85*qty);
                        else if(itemSize=="Grande")
                            itemPrice = (105*qty);
                        else(itemSize=="Venti")
                            itemPrice = (125*qty);
                    }
                    if(itemName=="Flat White")
                    {
                        if(itemSize=="Tall")
                            itemPrice = (75*qty);
                        else if(itemSize=="Grande")
                            itemPrice = (100*qty);
                        else(itemSize=="Venti")
                            itemPrice = (125*qty);
                    }

                }
                document.getElementById("subTotal").value = itemPrice;

                TotalPrice+=itemPrice;

                    if(itemName=="Caffe Latte")
                        {
                            document.getElementById('itemName').value += "\n" + "Caffe Latte" ;
                            document.getElementById('price').value += "\n" + itemPrice;
                            document.getElementById('qty').value +=  "\n" + qty;
                            document.getElementById('TotalPrice').value = TotalPrice;
                        }
                    else if(itemName=="Caffe Americano")
                        {
                            document.getElementById('itemName').value += "\n" + "Caffe Americano" ;
                            document.getElementById('price').value += "\n" + itemPrice;
                            document.getElementById('qty').value +=  "\n" + qty;
                            document.getElementById('TotalPrice').value = TotalPrice;
                        }
                    else if(itemName=="Cappuccino")
                        {
                            document.getElementById('itemName').value += "\n" + "Cappuccino" ;
                            document.getElementById('price').value += "\n" + itemPrice;
                            document.getElementById('qty').value +=  "\n" + qty;
                            document.getElementById('TotalPrice').value = TotalPrice;
                        }
                    else if(itemName=="Espresso")
                        {
                            document.getElementById('itemName').value += "\n" + "Espresso" ;
                            document.getElementById('price').value += "\n" + itemPrice;
                            document.getElementById('qty').value +=  "\n" + qty;
                            document.getElementById('TotalPrice').value = TotalPrice;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            document.getElementById('itemName').value += "\n" + "Flat White" ;
                            document.getElementById('price').value += "\n" + itemPrice;
                            document.getElementById('qty').value +=  "\n" + qty;
                            document.getElementById('TotalPrice').value = TotalPrice;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        alert("Invalid Quantity!!");
                }
                else
                    alert("Please Enter Quantity!!");


function Payment()
{
    var payment = document.getElementById('paymnet').value.trim();
    var TotalPrice = document.getElementById('TotalPrice').value;

    if (payment !="")
    {
        if (payment.match(/^[0-9]+$/))
        {
            if (TotalPrice < payment)
            {
                var change = payment - TotalPrice;

                document.getElementById('change').value= "Php" + change + ".00";
                TotalPrice=0;
            }
            else
                alert("Invalid Amount Entered!!");
        }
        else
            alert("Invalid Amount Entered!!");
    }
    else
        alert("Please Entered!!");
}

function NewTransaction(targ1,targ2,targ3)
{
    var OK = confirm("Are you sure you want to make New Transaction? \n OK or CANCEL? ");

    if (OK==true)
        targ1.value="";
        targ2.value="";
        targ3.value="";
        TotalPrice=0;
        document.getElementById('itemName').value ="";
        document.getElementById('price').value ="";
        document.getElementById('qty').value ="";
        document.getElementById('TotalPrice').value ="";
        document.getElementById('payment').value="";
        document.getElementById('change').value="";
}

     </head>
 <body>
 <div id="form">
 <legend class="wrap"><h3>COFFEE SHOP!</h3></legend>
 <h4>TRANSACTION FORM</h4>
 <div class="content">
 <div class="left">
 Item Name: 
 </div>
 <div class="right">
 <select id="itemName">
 <option selected disabled="disabled">SELECT ITEM</option>
 <option>Caffe Latte</option>
 <option>Caffe Americano</option>
 <option>Cappuccino</option>
 <option>Espresso</option>
 <option>Flat White</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
 <div class="left">
 Item Size: 
 </div>
 <div class="right">
 <select id="itemSize">
 <option selected disabled="disabled">SELECT SIZE</option>
 <option>Tall</option>
 <option>Grande</option>
 <option>Venti</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
 <div class="left">
 Quantity: 
 </div>
 <div class="right">
 <input type="text" id="QuanVal">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
 <div class="left">
 Price:  
 </div>
 <div class="right">
 <input type="text" id="subTotal" disabled="disabled">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="btnContent">
 <input type="button" value="ADD ITEM" onclick="AddItem()" style="background-color: grey; margin:3px; border-radius: 5px;">
 </div>
 <div class="btnContent">
 <input type="button" value="NEW TRANSACTION" onclick="NewTransaction(document.getElementById('itemName'),document.getElementById('QuanVal'),document.getElementById('subTotal'))" style="background-color: grey; margin:3px; border-radius: 5px;">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="form2">
 <div class="content">
 <div class="inline-div">
 <p align="center">Item Name</p>
 <textarea cols="15" rows="15" class="inline-txtarea" id="itemName" disabled="disable"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div class="inline-div">
 <p align="center">Price</p>
 <textarea cols="15" rows="15" class="inline-txtarea" id="price" disabled="disable"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div class="inline-div">
 <p align="center">Quantity</p>
 <textarea cols="15" rows="15" class="inline-txtarea" id="qty" disabled="disable"></textarea>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="btnContent" style="width: 180px; padding-top: 5px;">
  TOTAL PRICE:  
 <input type="text" id="TotalPrice" disabled="disabled">
 </div>
 <div class="btnContent" style="width: 180px; padding-left: 18px; padding-top: 5px;">
 ENTER PAYMENT:
 <input type="text" id="payment">
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="button" value="SUBMIT PAYMENT" onclick="Payment()" style="background-color: grey; margin:3px; border-radius: 5px;">
 CHANGE :
 <input type="text" id="change" disabled="disabled">
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please add html or put working snippet of your problem

Comment: i edited the thread and added my HTML. im really confused how things work. maybe i should read the basics.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you use an object for the product's prices.

Changes:

- using small variable and function names
- `id` for collections
- some other `id`
- using an object for propducts and their size
- exit early principle for checking requirements
- collections does not show an empty line in advance
- keeping `totalPrice` while payment
- complete reseting all inputs in `newTransaction`
- `newTransaction` without parameters

```js
var totalPrice = 0,
    products = {
        "Caffe Latte": {
            Tall: 75,
            Grande: 105,
            Venti: 135
        },
        "Caffe Americano": {
            Tall: 80,
            Grande: 100,
            Venti: 120
        },
        Cappuccino: {
            Tall: 70,
            Grande: 95,
            Venti: 120
        },
        Espresso: {
            Tall: 85,
            Grande: 105,
            Venti: 125
        },
        "Flat White": {
            Tall: 75,
            Grande: 100,
            Venti: 125
        }
    };

function addItem() {
    var itemPrice,
        itemName = document.getElementById('itemName').value,
        itemSize = document.getElementById('itemSize').value,
        quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value.trim(),
        subTotal = document.getElementById('subTotal').value;

    if (!products[itemName]) {
        alert("Please Enter Item Name!");
        return;
    }
    if (!(itemSize in products[itemName])) {
        alert("Please Enter Item Site!");
        return;
    }
    if (quantity === "") {
        alert("Please Enter Quantity!");
        return;
    }
    if (!quantity.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
        alert("Invalid Quantity!!");
        return;
    }
    itemPrice = quantity * products[itemName][itemSize];
    totalPrice += itemPrice;
    document.getElementById("subTotal").value = itemPrice;
    document.getElementById('collectionItemName').value += itemName + "\n";
    document.getElementById('collectionPrice').value += products[itemName][itemSize] + "\n";
    document.getElementById('collectionQuantity').value += quantity + "\n";
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = totalPrice;
}

function payment() {
    var payment = document.getElementById('payment').value.trim(),
        change;

    if (!payment) {
        alert("Please Enter Payment!");
        return;
    }
    if (!payment.match(/^\d+$/)) {
        alert("Invalid Amount Entered!");
        return;
    }
    if (totalPrice > payment) {
        alert("Payment is not enough!");
        return;
    }
    change = payment - totalPrice;
    document.getElementById('change').value = "Php" + change + ".00";
}

function newTransaction() {
    var ok = confirm("Are you sure you want to make New Transaction? \n OK or CANCEL? ");
    if (ok) {
        totalPrice = 0;
        document.getElementById('itemName').selectedIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById('itemSize').selectedIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById('subTotal').value = "";
        document.getElementById('quantity').value = "";
        document.getElementById("subTotal").value = "";
        document.getElementById('collectionItemName').value = "";
        document.getElementById('collectionPrice').value = "";
        document.getElementById('collectionQuantity').value = "";
        document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = "";
        document.getElementById('payment').value = "";
        document.getElementById('change').value = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
    <h3>COFFEE SHOP!</h3>
    <h4>TRANSACTION FORM</h4>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left">Item Name:</div>
        <div class="right">
            <select id="itemName">
                <option selected disabled="disabled">SELECT ITEM</option>
                <option>Caffe Latte</option>
                <option>Caffe Americano</option>
                <option>Cappuccino</option>
                <option>Espresso</option>
                <option>Flat White</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left">Item Size:</div>
        <div class="right">
            <select id="itemSize">
                <option selected disabled="disabled">SELECT SIZE</option>
                <option>Tall</option>
                <option>Grande</option>
                <option>Venti</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left">Quantity:</div>
        <div class="right"><input type="text" id="quantity"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left">Price:</div>
        <div class="right"><input type="text" id="subTotal" disabled="disabled"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="btnContent">
        <input type="button" value="ADD ITEM" onclick="addItem()" style="background-color: grey; margin:3px; border-radius: 5px;">
    </div>
    <div class="btnContent">
        <input type="button" value="NEW TRANSACTION" onclick="newTransaction()" style="background-color: grey; margin:3px; border-radius: 5px;">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="form2">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inline-div">
            <p align="center">Item Name</p>
            <textarea cols="15" rows="15" class="inline-txtarea" id="collectionItemName" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-div">
            <p align="center">Price</p>
            <textarea cols="15" rows="15" class="inline-txtarea" id="collectionPrice" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-div">
            <p align="center">Quantity</p>
            <textarea cols="15" rows="15" class="inline-txtarea" id="collectionQuantity" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btnContent" style="width: 180px; padding-top: 5px;">
        TOTAL PRICE:
        <input type="text" id="totalPrice" disabled="disabled">
    </div>
    <div class="btnContent" style="width: 180px; padding-left: 18px; padding-top: 5px;">
        ENTER PAYMENT:
        <input type="text" id="payment">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" value="SUBMIT PAYMENT" onclick="payment()" style="background-color: grey; margin:3px; border-radius: 5px;">
        CHANGE :
        <input type="text" id="change" disabled="disabled">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh. i didn't know about that upper&lower case thing. thanks for the help.